# How to return id of each array in Session Array?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to return the ids of each array in my session cart however at the moment it is not working correctly because i am only returning the position of the array which is not working when i go to remove the item from the array.
So how can i return the actual id of the array code below:

Current Array:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(1) {
[1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["start"]=>
    string(18) "name"
    ["end"]=>
    string(19) "name"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
}
```

From the above i am trying to retrieve 1 from [1]=> where later i will use to delete the array using $_SESSION['cart'][$arrayId];

for now i am counting the loops in the array using $i but this is insufficient.

So to reiterate i am trying to return the "[1]" id from [1]=>, unless there is another method that is better i would be all ears :)

Hope this makes sense everyone.
Alex

Addtional info:

Lets say i am inside the loop at the moment, can i somehow call the id from inside the foreach loop?

Comment: What's the criterion for arriving at "[1]"? You want *the first key* of the array? You want *the key where the `start` value is something specific*? You just want *any* key from the array?

Comment: Also: `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $item) echo $id; ..`

Comment: @deceze is it correct then that return $cart would return the key of the array in the following: foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $cart): echo $cart; endforeach; ?

Comment: No. `foreach (.. as $value)` iterates only over the values, `foreach (.. as $key => $value)` iterates over keys and values. Please [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: @deceze can you please write this as an answer it worked perfectly. And i learnt something new today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over an array's *keys and values*, use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value/* something */) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) is what you need.

If you just need the id of a row in the array, you can do the following:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $array) {
    echo $id; // $id will be the value of the keys of the looped array.
}
```

Comment: would that be able to be returned while inside the loop?

Comment: trying to return the specific key for the loop i am in.

Comment: Edited my answer to fulfill your needs. Also just noticed the answer was already provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = array_keys($_SESSION['cart']);
```